# ng-bootstrap table sortable with date field Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ng-bootstrap

I have to Sort An Observable Array having Date datatype With Sort() Method using Angular 13. Following example at:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table-sorting-aabk9h?file=app%2Ftable-sortable.ts

My table-sortable.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="countriesListAll$ | async as countries">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col" sortable="name" (sort)="onSort($event)">Country</th>
    <th scope="col" sortable="area" (sort)="onSort($event)">Area</th>
    <th scope="col" sortable="datewithtime" (sort)="onSort($event)">Dates celebrated</th>
    <th scope="col" sortable="population" (sort)="onSort($event)">Population</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let country of countries">
    <th scope="row">{{ country.id }}</th>
    <td>
      <img [src]="'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/' + country.flag" class="me-2" style="width: 20px">
      {{ country.name }}
    </td>
    <td>{{ country.area | number }}</td>
    <td>{{ country.datewithtime }}</td>
    <td>{{ country.population | number }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</ng-container>
```

The only difference from example is I get list of countries from countriesList$ observable

My table-sortable.ts

```
import { Component, Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

interface Country {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  flag: string;
  area: number;
  datewithtime: Date;
  population: number;
}

export type SortColumn = keyof Country | '';
export type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc' | '';
const rotate: {[key: string]: SortDirection} = { 'asc': 'desc', 'desc': '', '': 'asc' };

const compare = (v1: string | number, v2: string | number) => v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0;

export interface SortEvent {
  column: SortColumn;
  direction: SortDirection;
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'th[sortable]',
  host: {
    '[class.asc]': 'direction === "asc"',
    '[class.desc]': 'direction === "desc"',
    '(click)': 'rotate()'
  }
})
export class NgbdSortableHeader {

  @Input() sortable: SortColumn = '';
  @Input() direction: SortDirection = '';
  @Output() sort = new EventEmitter<SortEvent>();

  rotate() {
    this.direction = rotate[this.direction];
    this.sort.emit({column: this.sortable, direction: this.direction});
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-table-sortable',
  templateUrl: './table-sortable.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class NgbdTableSortable extends MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

  newQuery: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  filterForm: FormGroup;
  countriesListAll$: Observable<Country[]>;
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();
    this.bindForm();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      super.ngOnDestroy();
  }
  
  get countriesList$() {
    return this.countriesFacade.getCountries(); // to get list of countries
  }
```

countriesListAll() {
this.countriesListAll$ = this.countriesFacade.getCountries();
}

```
   get flatCountries(): Countries[] {  // to get flat object from observable
    return this.countriesFacade.getCountries().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
      tap(type => {
        this.countriesList = type;
        this.cd();
      })
    ).subscribe();
    console.log('In flatCountries() :',this.countriesList );
    return this.countriesList;
  }

  countriesAll = this.flatCountries;
  @ViewChildren(NgbdSortableHeader) headers: QueryList<NgbdSortableHeader>;

  onSort({column, direction}: SortEvent) {

    // resetting other headers
    this.headers.forEach(header => {
      if (header.sortable !== column) {
        header.direction = '';
      }
    });

    // sorting countries
    if (direction === '' || column === '') {
      this.countriesListAll$= this.countriesListAll$;
    } else {
      this.countriesListAll$ = this.countriesListAll$.pipe(map(data => data.sort((a, b) => {
    const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
    return direction === "asc" ? res : -res;
  })));
    }
  }

}
```

My sorting is not working for Date field. How to sort date field here which will have time as well like 21-DEC-2020 14:10:00

Comment: Sadly, your demo is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the compare part:

```
const compare = (v1: string | number | Date, v2: string | number | Date) => ( v1<v2 ? -1 : v1>v2 ? 1:0);
```

(in case someone still needs the answer :)